# Sharing KeyHandlers from MainWindow with a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a UserControl that currently has a few PreviewKeyDown event listeners, I would like to move these listeners to the MainWindow so that they work not only when the UserControl is the active focus, is there any way to achieve this?

The reason I have them in the UserControl is that the action of the PreviewKeyDown event depends on what TabItem is selected in the UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle PreviewKeyDown at MainWindow level and KeyDown and UserControl  level. But best would be to handle preview events at container level like Grid/StackPanel etc. Because at Window level many Preview events will be reached from various controls.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfUserControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:WpfUserControl"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="605.263" Width="701.316" PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="103*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="217*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <uc:UserControl1 Background="Aqua"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```